# Java 8 : functional way to write sort, filter and count at same time

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am pretty new to Java, and I am trying to write the below logic in functional way.

I have a list of Objects, which have many fields. `List<someObject>`
The fields of interest for now are `long timestamp` and `String bookType`

The problem statement is - I want to find the count of number of Objects in given list which have the same `bookType` as the one with lowest timestamp.

For example, if we sort the given list of objects based on `timestamp` in ascending order, and the first object in the sorted list has `bookType` field as `SOMETYPE` ; then I want to find out how many Objects are there in the list with the `bookType` `SOMETYPE`

I have written this logic using the plain old non functional way, by maintaing 2 temp variables and then iterating over the list once to find the lowest `timestamp` and the corresponding `bookType` amd a count of each `bookType`

But this is not acceptable to be run in a lambda, as it requires variables to be `final`

I could only write the part where I could sort the given list based on `timestamp`

```
n.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(someObject::timestamp)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am stuck how to proceed with finding the count of the lowest `timestamp` `bookType`

Comment: You don't need to sort. Only to find the object with the lowest timestamp. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-. Then you need to do a second pass and filter the stream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-), and the count the number of filtered elements (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--)

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot for the guidance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But this is not acceptable to be run in a lambda, as it requires variables to be final

First of all - this is not a problem since you can make your variable [Effectively final](http://ilkinulas.github.io/programming/java/2016/03/27/effectively-final-java.html) by creating eg. single entry array and pass its single (first) object to the lambda

Second thing is that there's basically no sense to put everything in one lambda - think about this, how logically finding `min` value is connected with counting objects grouped by some attribute? **It is not** - putting this (somehow) to one stream will just obfuscate your code

What you should do - you should prepare method to find `min` value and returning you it's `bookType` then stream collection and group it by `bookType` and return size of the collection with given key value

It could look like on this scratch:

```
public class Item {
    private final long timestamp;
    private final String bookType;

    // Constructors, getters etc
}

// ...

public int getSizeOfBookTypeByMinTimestamp() {
    return items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getBookType))
        .get(getMin(items))
        .size();
}

private String getMin(List<Item> items) {
    return items
        .stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparingLong(Item::getTimestamp))
        .orElse( /* HANDLE NO OBJECT */ ) // you can use also orElseThrow etc
        .getBookType();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance.

Comment: It’s horribly inefficient, to collect everything into a `Map<String,List<Item>>`, just to get the size of a single list. By using `Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getBookType, Collectors.counting())`, you would omit the creation of the `List<Item>` but count in the first place. Still, it would be doing too much work by counting irrelevant things. Just do `String minType = getMin(items);` first, followed by `return items.stream() .filter(item -> item.getBookType().equals(minType)) .count();`. Note that `count()` returns a `long`, so if an `int` is required, a cast is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to first find the item with the lowest timestamp and then filter the list for items with a matching timestamp. So in two steps:

```
Book first = n.stream().min(Comparator.comparingLong(someObject::timestamp).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
List<Book> result = n.stream().filter(b -> b.timestamp.equals(first.timestamp)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: op wants the matching bookType, not timestamp, no? So your second stream should be `n.stream().filter(b -> b.bookType.equals(first.bookType)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance.